# ImportError: cannot import name 'ReducedRegressionForecaster' from 'sktime.forecasting.compose'

Tags: python, sktime

```
from sktime.forecasting.compose import ReducedRegressionForecaster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because that doesn't exist.

https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime/blob/master/sktime/forecasting/compose/__init__.py

That's not exported by the library. Perhaps you wanted `RegressionForcaster` or `RecursiveRegressionForecaster`

Comment: I don't know why it is not imported but people are using reducedRegressionForecaster. I saw many articles based on ReducedRegressionForecaster

Comment: The named changed to `ReducedForecaster` - this is a bit of an oversight on our sight. We shouldn't have changed the name in a minor version update. sktime is still a really young project. Some features are not consolidated yet and are likely to change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the version to 0.5.2 works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).